# how to extract a substring "TIPO #' from text

Tags: python, pandas, string, python-re

i have a this strings in a pandas column:

```
"PAC_Clinker Tipo I Horno horizontal 3" 
"PAC_Clinker OTP Tipo V Horno horizontal 4" 
"PAC_Cemento Qhuna 4 5 Tipo I Despacho"
```

and i need as a result in other column the following result

```
Tipo I
Tipo V
TIpo I
```

Comment: Could you share any code snippets you tried? Or what error are you experiencing?

Comment: Something like `"Tipo \w+"` should work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regex to split off the substring:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["PAC_Clinker Tipo I Horno horizontal 3",
                            "PAC_Clinker OTP Tipo V Horno horizontal 4",
                            "PAC_Cemento Qhuna 4 5 Tipo I Despacho"]
                   })

df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.extract(r'(Tipo\s+\w+)')
```

which gives:

```
                                        col1    col2
0      PAC_Clinker Tipo I Horno horizontal 3  Tipo I
1  PAC_Clinker OTP Tipo V Horno horizontal 4  Tipo V
2      PAC_Cemento Qhuna 4 5 Tipo I Despacho  Tipo I
```